# Class AB power amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I have implemented a class AB amplifier. The schematics are below.

[image: My class AB amplifier schematics]

As you can see, my \$V_{cc}\$ is only 1V. How come I can still suppy 2.8 amp to the 4 ohm speaker/load? Is it a bug in MultiSim, or did the input signal (16V pk AC) made its way to the speaker? As far as I know, the voltage output in the load cannot exceed \$V_{cc}\$.

Both transistor appear to be in good placement/direction, but I've seen other configurations in which the transistors are reverted.

Here is a [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?4pgt256h21b6x9m) to my schematic.

**Safety question:** Is it ok for my 4 ohm speaker pass the whopping 2.8 amps? Is it common for power amplifiers to do that?

Comment: Your text says the load is 8 ohms but your schematic says 4. Your supply rail is a fraction of the specified input swing. No negative feedback, but positive feedback. This monstrosity will both clip and oscillate. I suggest you go back to the books. Not a real question.

Comment: edited. 8 ohms was a typo. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work.  You cannot drive the the transistors above the collector voltage otherwise the Vbc becomes forward biased.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have connected the output directly to the input.  Even if that is corrected, the input signal will go to the load through the base-emitter junctions of the transistors.

A class AB output stage will have a voltage gain of alpha, which is slightly less than 1.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by driving your circuit with 16V.