# How to get an output voltage of 16 Vpk on my preamplifier

Tags: amplifier

I'm trying to vary the resistors here in my preamplifier so that I would get a 16 Vpk output voltage, but as you can see here the output voltage is currently 0.209 V. Can someone please help me find the right resistor values to make an output voltage of 16 Vpk?

[image]

Comment: would u mind linking here the schematic for the circuit.also, i suggest you check for the operating condition for both transistors if they are in active region

Comment: The first thing that caught my eye is the 8 ohm load resistor.  Why?  You need a *power amp* to drive a load like that.  Your preamp output impedance is roughly 500 ohms so you're loosing more than 98% of the open circuit gain by voltage division.  The first thing to do is to replace that 8 ohm resistor with, say, a 50k resistor and see what your output looks like.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri how do we get the proper output impedance value? let's say we have a power amp attached to the pre amp, (we replace that RL by the whole power amp, and Rl is now connected to the output of the power amp. it sounds complicated.. )

Comment: The input impedance of the power amp will be at least 10k, more like 20k or even 50-100k in practice. What kind of power amplifier needs a 16V input signal? Or are you talking about the output of the *power* amp being 16V? What's the question here?

Comment: @EJP my power amplifier -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/LLKeq.png class AB push pull complimentary mode

Comment: This is making less and less sense. You are delivering 16V into a power amplifier that only has a 1V supply rail. It will clip. Both will distort. The voltage gain and the 8ohm load should both be in the power amp. Both the preamp and the power amp need negative feedback. Everything that could possibly be wrong is wrong with this.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a overall voltage gain of about 40, which is certainly doable with two transistor stages.  That's a gain of about 6.5 per stage.  Fidelity and gain predictability is another matter, which your circuit is not well designed for.

The biggest loss of gain in your circuit is that you are loading the output with only 8 Ω.  That is guaranteed to heavily load the signal considering it is in part driven from a 500 Ω pullup.

You say this is a preamp, but the output impedances of each stage and particularly the final load impedance don't make sense for that.  You have rather low collector resistors of 500 Ω, which will limit the gain.  You have to decide what output impedance you really need from each stage.  What does this preamp need to drive?

Comment: pre amp will drive power amp http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49259/class-ab-power-amplifier

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that this design is a learning exercise and not a "real" design so, rather than tell you to start over, I'd like to point out what to expect.

The 8-ohm load issue aside, the cascade of common emitter circuits that you show has some significant problems not least of which is that this circuit is linear only for very small signals.

I believe that you will find that using this design produces very high distortion for large signals.

The reason for this is that a BJT is inherently and highly non-linear.

For linear amplification, designers use local and global negative feedback to trade gain for linearity.

The circuit shown has *no* local or global AC feedback and thus, will be very non-linear except for very small signals.

Besides linearizing the circuit, global negative feedback also can be used to decrease output impedance.

Comment: I agree. Since the 1st stage emitter is bypassed , the low impedance will be reflected into the base such that positive swing signals will get shunted more than negative give an asymmetrical wave. Once you learn the non-ideal characteristics of simple circuits, you will appreciate the feedback and bias circuits that make them more linear and constant impedance using current source bias etc.  basic CE amp can be modded >> http://goo.gl/dzeDk  allow a few seconds to load.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you can frankly. That's 80x the existing gain. Even if you can get that from those two transistors without destroying whatever mediocre distortion performance it already has, it's not likely that the circuit will be able to source and sink the necessary current.

It's not much of a circuit. I would throw it out and start again.

And if this is a preamp, why does it have an 8-ohm load?

Comment: He needs 80x what he has now, but note that he is currently attenuating by over 2x.  Overall he needs about 40x voltage gain, which is really not out of line for two transistors.  Each stage only needs sqrt(40) = 6.3, which is quite doable.